# Python/Excel Assistance

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

New to python attempting to create a script that reads a batch of similarly formatted excel files (2k to be exact) from a folder, extracts the data, formats the data, and loads the data in a single consolidated excel file

any tips on how to go about this?

anything helps! thanks!

this is what I've accomplished so far. 
A loop to read through a folder

```
import os

rootdir = 'C:\Users\MikeV\Desktop\Folder'

for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print os.path.join(subdir,file)
```

Need help with the next step now reading and extracting the data from the worksheet(0) of each file

Comment: Check this out for useful python modules and tutorial docs. http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: @RafaelBarros this is what I've accomplished so far. A loop to read through a folder  import os
#create directory from which to pull the files
rootdir = 'C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\Mults'

for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print os.path.join(subdir,file)

Comment: @MikeV. have you checked the library `glob`? it's on the stdlib of python.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this function in my library: [pyexcel.cookbook.merge_all_to_a_book](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel/blob/master/pyexcel/cookbook.py#L95). Here's the [documentation](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#merge-all-excel-files-in-directory-into-a-book-where-each-file-become-a-sheet) about the usage you described.

You will need to customize `merge_all_to_a_book` to suit your formatting needs. I imagine, at line [121](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel/blob/master/pyexcel/cookbook.py#L121), you may need to get the data as array or dictionary, do some formatting with your data and then write them back as [a dict](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel/blob/master/pyexcel/writers.py#L214) or [an array](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel/blob/master/pyexcel/writers.py#L185) into a new sheet.